# How to export glb with transparent material(alpha) from fbx using fbxtogltf?

Tags: three.js, webgl, gltf, babylonjs

I tried exporting the fbx model into glb using following snippet

```
const convert = require('fbx2gltf');
   convert('/home/user/Desktop/projecta/ADELoID/Mercedes_Benz_GLE_class.FBX', 
   '/home/user/Desktop/projecta/ADELoID/enzo.glb').then(
   destPath => {
   },
   error => {
       console.log(error);
      }
   );
```

here's the resulting file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Xw03HRlZzjUrIUFzjsiNDwafK9eMJAr/view

When I view this in in https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ or https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/ where it appears as follows [image]

while in blender it appears with transparent glasses.As follows [image]

Comment: Since the model is appearing consistently in multiple glTF viewers, this seems to be a bug or limitation in the FBX2GLTF converter. You may need to file a bug there. Or if you can share the FBX file, SO users might be able to suggest other ways to convert it, such as Blender.